# Uploaded Images URL are incorrect

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

My *first* question, bear with me as I make mistakes.  Thanks!

Here's my setup:

- Ubuntu 12 Linux local dev instance
- Running GAE SDK
- Target Application is Wordpress 4.3.1

Note: App is installed is appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project from github.
I had to upgrade WP from the submodule that github repo refers to.

Fairly straightforward so far.

The question/issue I'm encountering is related to uploaded images served from local dev instance of GAE.  I upload a simple jpg and it is stored in SDK's blobstore. I've confirmed it in the developer console. But, the image URLs generated by Wordpress + GAE plugin for Wordpress are returning URLs that are just returning the image's metadata, see below.

When the browser attempts to load the URL, these are the headers:

```
Request URL: http://192.168.33.10:8080/_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/FunnyPrincesses.jpg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.33.10:8080
Response Headers
content-length:340
content-type:binary/octet-stream
Date:Thu, 07 Jan 2016 21:18:01 GMT
etag:4db1cc60d2325909fb07c042eb0ba9f6
last-modified:Thu, 07 Jan 2016 15:01:03 GMT
Server:Development/2.0
x-goog-stored-content-length:340
```

...and downloaded file contents (because content type = binary/octet-stream):

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 29392
Content-MD5: MDZjZGYwNDM4NmEzNDczZWVkZTRlYTVlNGMyY2FlM2U=
X-AppEngine-Cloud-Storage-Object: /gs/app_default_bucket/fake-GCRGQ7geNkrv5IC70HDksA==
content-disposition: form-data; name="async-upload"; filename="FunnyPrincesses.jpg"
X-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2016-01-07 15:01:00.995332
```

Appreciate for any help. Gracias!

**Update (1/11/16):** Added link to screen capture of admin attachment detail modal.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzPBT.png

Comment: My advice: stop using wordpress.

Comment: Do you see this problem only in dev server, or in production too?

Comment: Have not tried production yet, so just dev server.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to generate the serving URLs?

Comment: I am using the vanilla code that came with GAE to generate the links.  To demonstrate I added a link to screencapture of the attachment details modal. Note that the modal reports the image size is 340 bytes, which is wrong obviously.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the vanilla code that came with GAE".  Was it code from a specific doc? Code included in the sample project? Without knowing exactly what you are doing it's not possible to answer a question that requires troubleshooting.

Comment: The URL looks correct to me but 340B size seems a bit small for an image?

Comment: Are you specifying your own php interpreter or using the one included with the sdk? When I was developing WordPress using the App Engine SDK I couldn't use xdebug with the included php interpreter and when I used my own interpreter, I would see the issue you are describing.